# what is AlloyAUI's version in Liferay 7?

Tags: liferay-aui

browser the liferay home page in chrome，I get the following information from chrome's console：

```
YUI.version
3"patched-v3.18.1"
4> AUI.version
5"patched-v3.18.1"
```

so,I think AlloyUI's version is patched-v3.18.1,but I cann’t find this version in [alloyUI website](http://alloyui.com/)。
why？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay7 is use `AUI 3.0.x`.

You can read this [link](https://github.com/liferay/alloy-ui/wiki/Liferay-Integration).